# Jest, mocking ES6 class constructor not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I have code that I am trying to test with Jest. I have an ES6 class, let's call it `ClassA`. Within my test file, I am mocking `ClassA` as follows:

```js
const mockGetCheapestProductAllPages = jest.fn()
const ClassA = require('../src/ClassA/ClassA')
jest.mock('../src/ClassA/ClassA', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return { getCheapestProductAllPages: mockGetCheapestProductAllPages }
  })
})
```

This syntax works just fine for mocking the class. I am able to spy on `getCheapestProductAllPages` just fine, and mock return values from it, etc. The problem is, I cannot spy on the constructor for some reason. In the [Jest documentation on mocking ES6 classes](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#keeping-track-of-usage-spying-on-the-mock), it is implied that you can just reference the imported class in order to spy on the constructor, like so:

```js
expect(ClassA).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Unfortunately, this is not working for me. I know the constructor is being invoked in my test, but Jest tells me it is invoked 0 times. Any suggestions/anything look wrong? Tried to only share relevant code but please let me know if there is anything else you need to see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ended up declaring my Jest `mockImplementation` outside of my mock and referencing it in my tests like so:

```js
// top of test file
const mockGetCheapestProductAllPages = jest.fn()
const mockClassAImplementation = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return { getCheapestProductAllPages: mockGetCheapestProductAllPages }
})
const ClassA = require('../src/ClassA/ClassA')
jest.mock('../src/ClassA/ClassA', () => {
  return mockClassAImplementation
})

// tests
test('Expect ClassA constructor to be called', () => {
  // invoke method that invokes ClassA constructor
  // this works!
  expect(mockClassAImplementation).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```